# The simplest possible thermodynamic identity of a solid crystal, including a varying entropy and number of oscillators

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, entropy, chemical-potential

I would like to know if the term: $PdV$, can/should be included in the thermodynamic identity of a solid crystal. Let me clarify that the specific crystal is supposed to be having lost, a small $(\propto 10^{-2})$ proportion of its oscillators. So that its volume has decreased by a small amount.

Additionally, I would like to know if the thermodynamic identity: $$0 = TdS + \mu dN$$ can be applied in this case, further assuming that the internal energy $U$ of the crystal is held fixed $(U = qhf)$. $q$ is the number of energy quanta of the crystal, $h$ is Planck's constant and $f$ is the frequency of the quantum harmonic oscillators comprising the crystal. [This is Schroeder's definition of the internal energy of a solid crystal.]

Since a solid crystal is a lattice, I would claim that the specific volume: $\upsilon = \frac{V}{m}$, does not change by a varying $N$.

The chemical potential is given by: $\mu = -T\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N} \right)_{V,U} = -kT\ln(1 + \frac{q}{N})$. So we see that: $$\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N} \right)_{V,U} = k\ln(1 + \frac{q}{N})$$ So $\left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial N} \right)_{V,U}$ depends on $N$.

Finally since $f = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}}$, the internal energy $U = qhf$ is dependent on the unit mass. However, $U$ does not depend on $N$.

Comment: What specifically are you trying to determine?  Does the internal energy per unit mass and the entropy per unit mass of the sample change?  Does the specific volume change?

Comment: I am trying to determine the simplest possible relation between $dS$ and $dN$, in the case of a solid crystal.